AWS Glue Crawler is nor writing tables
I am having an issue when running the aws glue crawler, It does not generate any tables ..
Here is my terraform config, can anyone help please
  resource "aws_iam_role" "cu_test_glue_service_role" {
  name = "AWSGlueServiceRole"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
      Principal = {
        Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
      },
      Effect = "Allow",
    }]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "cu_test_glue_service_policy" {
  name       = "glue-service-role-policy"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.cu_test_glue_service_role.name]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole"
}
resource "aws_iam_policy" "cu_test_glue_s3_access_policy" {
  name        = "cu-test-glue-s3-access-policy"
  description = "Grants Glue service access to S3 buckets"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = [
            "s3:*",
            "s3-object-lambda:*"
        ],
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::cur-report-eu-west-1-xxxxxxxxxx",
          "arn:aws:s3:::cur-report-eu-west-1-xxxxxxxxxx/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cu_test_glue_s3_access_policy_attachment" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.cu_test_glue_s3_access_policy.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.cu_test_glue_service_role.name
}
resource "aws_glue_catalog_database" "cu_test_db" {
  name = "cu_test_data_db"
}

resource "aws_glue_crawler" "my_crawler" {
  name         = "my_cur_data_crawler_test"
  role         = aws_iam_role.cu_test_glue_service_role.arn
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.cu_test_db.name

  s3_target {
    path = "s3://cur-report-eu-west-1-xxxxxxxxxx/test/report_test/cost_and_usage_data_status/"
  }

  schema_change_policy {
    delete_behavior = "LOG"
  }
}

I am running the crawler via CLI and I have nothing suspicious on the glue crawler logs ..
aws glue start-crawler --name "my_cur_data_crawler_test"

CloudWatch Logs:

BENCHMARK : Running Start Crawl for Crawler my_cur_data_crawler_test
BENCHMARK : Classification complete, writing results to database
cu_test_data_db INFO : Crawler configured with SchemaChangePolicy
{"UpdateBehavior":"UPDATE_IN_DATABASE","DeleteBehavior":"LOG"}.
BENCHMARK : Finished writing to Catalog BENCHMARK : Crawler has
finished running and is in state READY


Does the Glue service role provide the necessary permissions for creating the tables?

@MarkoE It should be, I deleted the infra and recreated another iam_role with these permissions ' "logs:CreateLogGroup", "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents", "glue:UpdateDatabase", "glue:UpdatePartition", "glue:CreateTable", "glue:UpdateTable", "glue:ImportCatalogToGlue", "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"' but the issue is persisting .

I changed the s3_target path and It worked fine:
path = "s3://${var.s3_bucket_name}/${var.s3_bucket_prefix}/${var.report_name}/${var.report_name}"


I changed the s3_target path and It worked fine: path = "s3://${var.s3_bucket_name}/${var.s3_bucket_prefix}/${var.report_name}/${var.report_name}"
